# Why my variable "intervalId" is not getting the value updated when I call the function "StopTimer" function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my simple code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  var intervalId;

  function startTimer() {
    intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(time => time + 1);
    }, 1000);
    console.log("My interval id is: ", intervalId);
  }

  function stopTimer() {
    console.log("Clearing intervalId", intervalId);
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{time}</div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={startTimer}>Start time</button>
        <button onClick={stopTimer}>Stop time</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Here is the representation of the error](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-new?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

I press **Start Time button** and then the **Stop Time Button**, but my variable intervalId in the stopTimer function is not getting the updated value from the setInterval function. Why?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `intervalId` is not the same variable that was in scope when `startTimer` was invoked. It will be `undefined` in all the subsequent renders. ( caused when `time` change state )

In React, if you want to "keep a value" across the life cycle of a component, you can use a `ref` for it:

```
  // ....
  var intervalId = React.useRef();
  // ....
  intervalId.current = setInterval(() => {
  // ...
  clearInterval(intervalId.current);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `App` is invoked everytime you change the state (`setTime`), you get a new, fresh value of the local variable.

One of options is to include the variable in your state.

```
function App() {
  var [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  var [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(0);

  function startTimer() {
    setIntervalId(intervalId => setInterval(() => {
      setTime(time => time + 1);
    }, 1000));
  }

  function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{time}</div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={startTimer}>Start time</button>
        <button onClick={stopTimer}>Stop time</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```