# not able to clear Interval using variable which is outside the react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to access `clearTimerInterval` in `clearTimer` method but getting undefined , got the waring `variable from inside React Hook will be lost after each render`. in below code `useEffect` hook called once once then how variable `clearTimerInterval` got undefined?

```
function Child(props) {
          let [timerCount, setTimer] = useState(0);
          var clearTimerInterval;
          useEffect(() => {
            clearTimerInterval = setInterval(() => {
              setTimer(timerCount => {
                return timerCount + 1;

              });
            }, 1000);
            return () => {
              clearInterval(clearTimerInterval);
            };
          }, []);

          function clearTimer() {
            clearInterval(clearTimerInterval);
          }
          return (
            <div>
              <div>Timer {timer}</div>
              <button onClick={clearTimer}>ClearTimer</button>
            </div>
          );
        }

        export default React.memo(Child);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why my variable "intervalId" is not getting the value updated when I call the function "StopTimer" function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60467384/why-my-variable-intervalid-is-not-getting-the-value-updated-when-i-call-the-fu)

Answer (score 10):

If you need to save variables across re-renders use [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) which in this case acts like a class instance field, also note that mutations to refs does not trigger a re-render.

This will give you the ability to clear the interval from outside of `useEffect`

```js
function Child(props) {
  let [timerCount, setTimer] = useState(0)
  const intervalRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTimer(prevState => prevState + 1)
    }, 1000)

    return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current)
  }, [])

  function clearTimer() {
    clearInterval(intervalRef.current)
    intervalRef.current = null
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Timer {timerCount}</div>
      <button onClick={clearTimer}>ClearTimer</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I got it.

Answer (score -1):

Try defining the variable inside of the hook.

```
          useEffect(() => {
          var clearTimerInterval;
            clearTimerInterval = setInterval(() => {
              setTimer(timerCount => {
                return timerCount + 1;

              });
            }, 1000);
            return () => {
              clearInterval(clearTimerInterval);
            };
          }, []);
```